# Task isFaulted status not maintained unless the task.Result is assigned in local variable

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

Consider the following code snippet:

```
    public Task SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(string email, string password) {
        return auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) 
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            if (task.IsFaulted) 
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            var result = task.Result; // I need to do this to maintain the task fail status
        });
    }
```

If I call this method from other part of my code, like so:

```
var loginTask = firebaseManager.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(username, password);
yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => loginTask.IsCompleted);
Debug.Log(loginTask.IsFaulted) // true if I dont do var result = task.Result; in the original task
```

If the task fails I need do the `var result = task.Result;` to maintain the `IsFaulted` status. Without that line of code its always true (even if the task fails).

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell is the following. `ContinueWith` will return the a new Task instead of the one that it continues on, which makes sense. Therefore `.IsFaulted` will always be `false` when calling `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` as in fact, the Task you created inside of `ContinueWith` is not faulty.

However, when you try to access `task.Result` inside of the `.ContinueWith` method it will re-throw the exception and therefore the new task is also faulty. What you want in your code would be something like the following:

```cs
public Task SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(string email, string password) 
{
    return auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password)
        .ContinueWith(
            task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                    Console.WriteLine("faulted");
            
                return task;
            }).Unwrap();
}
```

What effectively happens is that `ContinueWith` will return `Task<Task>` where the outer `Task` is the one that represents the `ContinueWith` and the inner one the `Task` that it received as the previous one. Now when you call  `Unwrap` just gets you back the inner task.

Comment: Or use async/ await like a sane person would :)

Comment: In order to prevent all of that ContinueWith...

Comment: @Fildor I mean yes, this would make the most sense, nonetheless it doesn't answer the question being asked by the OP.

Comment: I agree. It wouldn't explain the observation. But as suggested improvement ...

Comment: Even async await can make more sense, without it I can choose when calling `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` to await for it or not. I was not aware that `ContinueWith` created a brand new task and how to access the inner one. Thanks very much @Twenty.

Comment: To note that I am not using `ContinueWith` in the question, I am using `var loginTask = firebaseManager.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(username, password);`. Problem seems to be the same though, that a brand new task its crated with its own status.